# A calculus of variation problem with Non-homogeneous Boundary Conditions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, calculus-of-variations

Find function $u(x,y,z)$ so that the function $I(u)$ to be optimized

$$I(u)=\iiint_{\Omega}(u_x^2+u_y^2+u_z^2-xyzu)\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dz $$

that

$$\Omega=\{(x,y,z):0\le x,y,z\le1\}$$

with

$$u(0,y,z)=y,\quad u(1,y,z)=z,\quad u_y(x,0,z)=x,\quad u(x,1,z)=z,\quad u(x,y,0)=y,\quad u(x,y,1)=x$$

Who can advise me? 
I tried to change four item of boundary conditions to homogeneous form , but i found that i can't do this and it's impossible, then i changed just two of them but in this case , i recived so much difficulities ...

Comment: What's the point of subtracting the term $xyz$ independent of $u$ that just shifts $I$ by a constant?

Comment: sorry.edited @joriki

Comment: Is the problem from a book or website?

Comment: Comment to the post (v6): This is [Dirichlet's principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_principle) for [Poisson's equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson's_equation) $2\nabla^2 u= -xyz$. An inhomogeneous particular solution to Poisson's equation (not respecting the boundary conditions) is $u=-\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{36}xyz$.